# Как найти моду в словаре (самое часто встречающиеся значение в словаре)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, статистика

Есть задача найти моду (самое часто встречающиеся значение в словаре). При чем по условию, если такого значения нет, т.е. все встречается по одному разу, необходимо вывести минимальное значение ключа словаря.

**Сейчас я делаю так:**

```
    some_dict = {64630: 1, 11735: 1, 14216: 1, 99233: 1, 14470: 1, 4978: 2, 73429: 1, 38120: 1, 51135: 1, 67060: 1}

for key,value in some_dict.items():
    if value == max(some_dict.values()):
        print(key)
```

Самое часто встречающее значение я смог найти.

**Вопрос**: Как вывести минимальное значение ключа словаря при условии, что все значения встречаются по одному разу?

Comment: Ничего не понял. Во-первых, у вас не рабочий код. Во-вторых, эти кодом вы найдете наибольшее значение в словаре (2), причем не ключа, а именно value. А исходя из ваших условий, самое часто встречающееся значение - 1.

Comment: Александр, не могли-бы Вы конкретней обрисовать задачу.

Comment: Andrey, да конечно. Смотрите, необходимо найти моду в словаре. Т.е. самое часто встречающееся значение. Но при этом словарь может, например состоять из 10 цифр, которые встречаются по одному разу. И тогда надо вывести минимальную цифру, а не минимальное количество повторений этой цифры. Т.е. цифра -ключ, а количество повторений этой цифры - значение по ключу.

Comment: @strawdog  ради бога простите, копировал свой код из функции и забыл отредактировать его. Спасибо, что обратили внимание.

Answer (score 1):

Определил значения в список `dd`. Затем нашёл пару `(<количество повторений>, <самое повторяемое значение>)`. Далее в условии определяем если количество повторении `> 1` то берём самое повторяемое ***значение***, иначе ищем минимальный ***ключ***:

```
d = {100: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 4}
dd = list(d.values())

res = max([(dd.count(s), s) for s in set(dd)], key=lambda x: x[0])
if res[0] > 1:
    print(res[1])
else:
    print(min(d.keys()))
```

Answer (score 1):

Построим словарь `c`, в котором ключи - значения `some_dict`, а значения - списки соответствующих ключей. Для словаря из вопроса `c` получится таким:

> ```
> {
>     1: [64630, 11735, 14216, 99233, 14470, 73429, 38120, 51135, 67060],
>     2: [4978]
> }
> ```

`max(map(len, c.values()))` вычисляет количество ключей соответствующих моде.

Отберём из `c.values()` все самые длинные значения, упорядочим их, выберем минимальное.

```
some_dict = {
    64630: 1, 11735: 1, 14216: 1, 99233: 1, 14470: 1,
    4978: 2, 73429: 1, 38120: 1, 51135: 1, 67060: 1
}

c = {}
for k, v in some_dict.items():
    c.setdefault(v, []).append(k)

max_c = max(map(len, c.values()))
min_k = min(sorted(v) for v in c.values() if len(v) == max_c)
print(min_k)
```

> ```
> [11735, 14216, 14470, 38120, 51135, 64630, 67060, 73429, 99233]
> ```